# Shape interpolation with quaternios using Eigen in C++/OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, eigen, quaternions, lerp

I am trying to implement shape interpolation between two triangles using quaternions as discussed in the 2000 paper *As-rigid-as-possible shape interpolation* by Alexa, Cohen-Or, and Levin.

Let's say Triangle 1 has points A, B, C, and Triangle 2 has points M, N, O. The two corresponding matrices (T1 and T2, respectively) are as follows:

```
T1 = {A.x, B.x, C.x},
     {A.y, B.y, C.y},
     {1,   1,   1  }

T2 = {M.x, N.x, N.x},
     {M.y, N.y, N.y},
     {1,   1,   1  }
```

I then take the inverse of T1 and multiply it by T2 to perform Singular Value Decomposition to get matrix SVD, to find the rotation and scaling matrix.

```
Eigen::Matrix3f A = T1.inverse().eval() * T2;
Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixXf> SVD;
SVD.compute(A, ComputeFullU | ComputeFullV);
Eigen::MatrixXf D = SVD.singularValues().asDiagonal().toDenseMatrix();
Eigen::Matrix3f rotationMatrix = SVD.MatrixU() * SVD.MatrixV();
Eigen::Matrix3f sMatrix = SVD.MatrixV() * D * SVD.MatrixV().transpose();
Eigen::Quaternionf quat = rotationMatrix;
```

I then use this quaternion and the sMatrix for interpolation. Note: timer starts at 0.0f and increases by 0.0001f(some small constant) until it reaches 1.0f. to animate the transformation.

```
Eigen::MatrixXf Rtime = (Quaternionf::Identity().slerp(timer, quat)).toRotationMatrix();
MatrixXf Stime = MatrixXf::Identity(3, 3) * (1 - timer) + sMatrix * timer;
Eigen::MatrixXf A = Rtime * ((1 - timer) * MatrixXf::Identity(3, 3) + timer * Stime);
```

I then turn each point P of the original triangle into its own 3x1 vector and multiply it by A.

```
Eigen::Vector3f v;
v(0) = P.x;
v(1) = P.y;
v(2) = 1;
v = At * v;
```

Finally, I draw a point at the new v(0) and v(1) and repeat for the other two vertices of the triangle.

While I get a new triangle at the location of the original triangle (T1) when timer is very small (close to 0), as timer increases, the new triangle scales and translates away from T1, but doesn't move towards the final triangle (T2).

The linear interpolation seems to work if I just use the matrix that I calculated by taking T1.inverse() and multiplying by T2. So, I think my issue is with the implementation of slerp or with the SVD but I'm not sure.

Is there anything else I should include that would be helpful in determining where I went wrong?

EDIT: Added Stime matrix, switched call of transpose on V matrix.

Comment: Not sure, but you might have a typo in the 2nd parameter of the slerp invocation: quart instead of quat?

Comment: @M.F. My bad! I forgot to change the name of the variable in the post, but thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: The result of `JacobiSVD` are matrices `U`, `D`, `V`, such that `A==U*D.asDiagonal()*V.transpose()` -- I guess, if you (un)-transpose all your `V` matrices, you should get something which looks ok. I there a particular reason why you are not simply linearly interpolating from Identity to `A`?

Comment: @chtz So I changed `Eigen::Matrix3f sMatrix = SVD.MatrixV().transpose() * D * SVD.MatrixV();` to `Eigen::Matrix3f sMatrix = SVD.MatrixV() * D * SVD.MatrixV().transpose();` This is closer to what I am looking for, but still not exact. I also added a new matrix Stime which will be edited into my original post. As for why, I am trying to implement As-Rigid-As-Possible Shape Interpolation as described by the authors of the paper that I mentioned. They state that linear interpolation would not be sufficient once applied to more complex figures.

Comment: You have to transpose the V in `rotationMatrix` as well ....

Comment: @chtz Oh yes. Thank you!

Comment: From my understanding of the paper, I believe what you are doing only really works for individual triangles. The paper states that you need to solve the least squares problem to extract the correct transformations.